# start sale on date nestjs

Tags: e-commerce, nestjs

I am busy building a e-commerce api using nestjs.

How will I be able to auto start a promotion/sale using a 'start' date and then again ending the promo using 'end' date.

I do already capture the start and end date. but not sure how to have it automated.

Comment: What do you mean by auto-start a promotion? You already have a start and end date for said promotion, right? What does it mean for the promotion to "start"?

Comment: so lets say the end_date is tomorrow. Should I have listeners in there looking at the date constantly, or is it as simple as having a function on a timer interval to check every 12h if the promotion is still valid or should start?

Maybe I am over thinking it. Just want the user to be able to have a start and end date and then compare to the current date and then start or stop accordingly.

Comment: Okay, but what does it mean to start the promotion? What does that mean for your server? Does it do anything special when the promotion starts?

Comment: Regardless of how it's supposed to work, you can try a rather primitive approach: set one-time `setInterval` that checks every X minutes/hours for end_date and automatically calls appropriate method to modify promotions.

Comment: The product should go on promotion during that time.

was also thinking of interval, but not sure if that is the best solution as multiple product will have different promotions etc.

Comment: But what does it mean for a product to go on promotion? The reason I bring it up is because you already have a record for the promotion, including start and end time. If it's a sale price or something you can always query against the promotion table, see if it's active, and apply the discount. I don't see the need to a CRON or timed job

Comment: ok well lets say its black friday, then the product should go on promotion for that day and that day only. the admin can login and select a product that will be on sale for that Friday, set a percentage discount and then say on Saturday the product should revert back to original state.
So that is what I mean with going on promotion, is a temporary change of price for a set time

Answer (score 2):

So the solution was nestJS task scheduling:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling

This allowed me to run a CRON job on a daily basis that will look at all the products on promotion and list them. It also gives me the option to run a specific time and date, which might come in handy if we run promotions like a flash promotion that runs within a specific time (12:00 - 14:00).